# Partial Masking in SQL - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, masking

Given table has debit card numbers. I want to write a code to mask the debit card numbers in which the middle 4 numbers are replaced with X. The table is as follows:

[image]

I want the following output:

[image]

I have written the following code but it is giving errors:

```
UPDATE
Debit_card_master
SET
Debit_card = LEFT(Debit_card, 4) + REPLICATE(‘x’, 4) + RIGHT(Debit_card, 4) ;
```

Also, can anyone help me with the correct MySQL code for the same?

Comment: Oracle uses `||` for string concatenation.  Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks kind of appropriate for MySQL (although not quite).  In Oracle, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace(debit_card, '^(....)(....)', '\1xxxx')
```

You can test this first.  In the `update`:

```
UPDATE Debit_card_master
    SET debit_card = regexp_replace(debit_card, '^(....)(....)', '\1xxxx');
```

Note:  This assumes that the number is always 12 characters.  Or, more specifically, it replaces the characters in position 5-8.

Comment: PDATE Debit_card_master
    SET debit_card = regexp_replace(debit_card, '^(....)(....)', '\1xxxx');

In the above command, what does this mean? '^(....)(....)' - Do I have to replace it with something?

Comment: That is the regular expression pattern.  It divides the first eight characters into two groups.  Then this is replaced by the first group and four `'x'`s.